# Mythbuntu zooms in on every video since upgrading to 12.04

Tags: mythbuntu

I have a computer dedicated to media playback running Mythbuntu that I have upgraded to 12.04.

Before, when playing high resolution and wide aspect ratio videos, they would be resized to fit the screen. So wide screen videos would be letterboxed. This is the desired behaviour.

Since the upgrade, any video I play back expands to fill the whole screen. It seems to zoom in to roughly the centre, though in some cases it seems to guess at top left, or something else. Whatever the algorithm, all videos are zoomed in so close that they look low resolution.

How do I get Mythbuntu to return to the desired behaviour of showing the whole frame inside my monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the MythTV Frontend setting

Setup/TV Settings (or Video)/Playback Page 2 of 8/Zoom

to be set to "Auto detect".

Comment: Further note to anyone who might come across this - I find that setting the zoom to "off" works better than "auto detect".